# Problem showing the predicted image in Tensorflow mnist tutorial

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, matplotlib

I'm working with the code from the Tensorflow [beginner mnist tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials) (code below).

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

 (x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
 x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

 model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
   tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
   tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
   tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
   tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
 ])
 model.compile(optimizer='adam',
               loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
               metrics=['accuracy'])

 model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
 model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Since the tutorial stops after evaluating the model, I have added a few lines to make actual predictions.

```
 predictions = model.predict([x_test])
 print(np.argmax(predictions[0]))
```

So far it all works. However I would like to see the image the model tries to predict to know what's going on. I therefore tried the following:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 plt.imshow(x_test[0])
 plt.show()
```

This does not work. I don't get an error message, it just won't show the picture. Furthermore if I try to add a simple print-statement after the matplotlib code that is ignored too and won't be printed. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You report that `.show()` does not work properly with your current config. Rather than call that you may prefer this:

```
plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

You can use that with a headless driver if you want:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Comment: The result is the same unfortunately. It is very strange. Matplotlib works fine both your solution and plt.show() if I remove the "predictions" code segment (in my code above). Otherwise I dont get anything, no error, no image. I suppse the program crashes since it doesn't execute any other code either below the matplotlib statements. I also noticed in the console that the number in "In [3]: runfile"... returns to 1 when I run my code. However if I keep the prediction code segment without matplotlib everything is fine too..

Comment: Hmm, maybe the GPU needs to be reset between using it for modeling and using it to display an image? In any event you'll want to learn where it crashes. Try: `$ gdb python mnist.py`, then `run`, and `bt` for a backtrace.

Comment: When I ran it through the terminal I got this: OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5.dylib, but found libiomp5.dylib already initialized.

Comment: Well, that's illuminating, now we're getting closer to the root cause. Installing multiple copies / versions of the library seems to be the problem. According to https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1715 doing an `uninstall` can be helpful. Also, `conda install nomkl` can be relevant.

Comment: Thanks! I found a solution in your link and now it works fine. Apparently this is a problem with Mac OS. One just has to add the following two statementts to the code to override the error: import os

os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'